# Power bi: Importing excel sheet with no table

Tags: excel, powerbi

In Power bi, I tried to import a excel file containing no table.
[image: Here is the template sample.]
The excel file is kind of a template. After importing,many rows are coming with no data and some rows with null values.
[image: In Power bi after importing]
Is it mandatory to have table in excel sheet that we are importing in Power bi? If not then any way to solve this import issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking how to eliminate the sheet header area and have PowerBI start with you actual data, then these steps will get you what you want.

First, I created an Excel file with your data in the layout you show. When I import it into PowerBI, I get something that looks like this.

[image: Start]

From here, you can have PowerBI remove rows, so we can skip the first four rows.

[image: Remove rows]

[image: Remove rows dialog]

Then finally, you can promote the first row to be used as headers.

[image: Promote headers]

The final results look like this.

[image: Results]

The nulls are the default when PowerBI reads a blank cell from Excel.

Comment: but X,Y,Z these values got truncated.

Comment: If you want to get those values into their own table, you can simply create another query to the same Excel sheet and remove columns and rows to limit it down to just those 6 cells and then promote the first row to headers. If that's not what you are looking for, I would suggest updating your question with an example of your desired results.